# Center Draggable Jquery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

For the last few hours I've been trying to have an animated dialog that will initiate a puff animation, is draggable and when closed will center again when opened. As of now I have it so the animation initiates, it's draggable but when I close and open it, it's fixed in the same position it was dragged to.

I've tried using the open function, complete function in show/hide, setting the div/dialog in a function, using position: center and yeah...

Anyway, here is the code:

frm_location.jsp:

//this is in an "a" tag, can't seem to get it to display properly

id="NEW_LOCATION_BUTTON" href="javascript:openDialog('#dialog-form','#popupBoxCancel','orange-theme','625');" class="btn_sel">

jQueryDialog.js:

function openDialog(_dialog, _cancel, _theme, _size) {

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(_dialog).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: _size,
            modal: true,
            position: "center",
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            dialogClass: _theme,
            show: {
                effect: "puff",
                percent: "-150",
                duration: 250

            },
            hide: {
                effect: "puff",
                percent: "-150",
                duration: 250,
            },
        });

    $(_cancel).click(function() {
        $(_dialog).dialog("close");
    });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this. I'm not sure how you're reopening the dialog, but this should do. [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/c23WH/)

```
<div id='dialog'>PUFF</div>
<button id='reopen'>OPEN DIALOG</button>

  $(function () {
    $('#reopen').click(function () {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ position: 'center'});
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 200,
        modal: true,
        position: "center",
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        show: {
            effect: "puff",
            percent: "-150",
            duration: 250

        },
        hide: {
            effect: "puff",
            percent: "-150",
            duration: 250,
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: I got this to work with a button which I was extremely happy about. However it seems I'm using an area tag which doesn't have a click event. I'll edit the OP with a more complete picture.